# AutoHotKey script that quickly finds an open window by title

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for a script that will allow me to start typing text and filter through the open windows (a list of titles will suffice) and select a window with a keyboard from the list.

The first option is to find an existing script. If that doesn't exist I'll try to create one.

So, is there such a script or something similar that I can take code from and save time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this:

> [iSwitchw - cosmetically enhanced edition](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33353)

Could that be what your looking for?

Comment: This is old, but I'm looking for something similar to work across mutliple desktops in Windows 10. This is close, maybe there's an updated version somewhere, or perhaps I'll try my hand at hacking it. I'm a beginner at AHK but an experienced dev, so perhaps, if I find time...