# Autohotkey: Find and focus windows by name accross virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, vnc

I'd like an ahk script to find and focus running windows across virtual desktops on Windows 10.

I found one earlier but alas forgot where it's from, maybe someone here knows. I think it was to help with special keys shortcuts not working in VNC sessions (Win key, alt-tab for example). Sadly, because it's quite good but lacks a keyboard search feature, rather it works with keyboard or mouse selection and sorts by most recently used. So if I could find an updated version, or its source (to contact its dev) which has this search feature, perfect! Here's the code I have:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


$F1:: AltTab()
$F2:: AltTabMenu()
$F4:: LWin
!`::WinClose, A  ; Alt-` = close window

; AltTab-replacement for Windows 8:
AltTab(){
    list := ""
    WinGet, id, list
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        IfWinActive, ahk_id %this_ID%
            continue    
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue
        If (!IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))) 
            continue
        WinActivate, ahk_id %this_ID%, ,2
            break
    }
}

; AltTabMenu-replacement for Windows 8:
AltTabMenu(){
    list := ""
    Menu, windows, Add
    Menu, windows, deleteAll
    WinGet, id, list
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue            
        If (!IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))) 
            continue
        Menu, windows, Add, %title%, ActivateTitle      
        WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, ahk_id %this_ID%
        Try 
            Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %Path%,, 0
        Catch 
            Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %A_WinDir%\System32\SHELL32.dll, 3, 0 
    }
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseMove, (0.4*A_ScreenWidth), (0.35*A_ScreenHeight)
    CoordMode, Menu, Screen
    Xm := (0.25*A_ScreenWidth)
    Ym := (0.25*A_ScreenHeight)
    Menu, windows, Show, %Xm%, %Ym%
}

ActivateTitle:
    SetTitleMatchMode 3
    WinActivate, %A_ThisMenuItem%
return

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
; Check whether the target window is activation target
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
IsWindow(hWnd){
    WinGet, dwStyle, Style, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if ((dwStyle&0x08000000) || !(dwStyle&0x10000000)) {
        return false
    }
    WinGet, dwExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (dwExStyle & 0x00000080) {
        return false
    }
    WinGetClass, szClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (szClass = "TApplication") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

for a script named `vnc special keys.ahk`, but this might be a name I gave it. Sorry not much more details on this, I've looked around (Google, Github) but haven't found it. And kids, remember to put a comment in your code with at least the author and source website :-P

Also found this [old 2010 script](https://superuser.com/questions/350238/autohotkey-script-that-quickly-finds-an-open-window-by-title)

Comment: To get all windows in all virtual desktops in the menu, add **`DetectHiddenWindows, On`** on the top of the script. See also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
F1::    
InputBox, UserInput, Find and focus running windows, Type part of a window title to display a menu with all possible matches.., , 300, 140
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, CANCEL was pressed.
    return
}   
else
{
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    list := ""
    Menu, windows, Add
    Menu, windows, deleteAll
    WinGet, id, list
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue            
        If (!IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))) 
            continue
        If !InStr(title, UserInput)
            continue
        Menu, windows, Add, %title%, ActivateWindow 
        WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, ahk_id %this_ID%
        Try 
            Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %Path%,, 0
        Catch 
            Menu, windows, Icon, %title%, %A_WinDir%\System32\SHELL32.dll, 3, 0 
    }
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseMove, (0.4*A_ScreenWidth), (0.35*A_ScreenHeight)
    CoordMode, Menu, Screen
    Xm := (0.25*A_ScreenWidth)
    Ym := (0.25*A_ScreenHeight)
    Menu, windows, Show, %Xm%, %Ym%
}
return


ActivateWindow:
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
WinActivate, %A_ThisMenuItem%
return

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
; Check whether the target window is activation target
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
IsWindow(hWnd){
    WinGet, dwStyle, Style, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if ((dwStyle&0x08000000) || !(dwStyle&0x10000000)) {
        return false
    }
    WinGet, dwExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (dwExStyle & 0x00000080) {
        return false
    }
    WinGetClass, szClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (szClass = "TApplication") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36008086/3419297